# jQuery: selecting all <option> tags inside <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(newb warning)

So i have a `<select>` tag with many `<option>` tags inside it, and I want to perform a thing on all of them at once with jQuery.

```
  <select id="select" multiple>
    <option id = "1" value="1">1</option>
    <option id = "2" value="234567890">234567890</option>
    <option id = "3" value="better">better</option>
    <option id = "4" value="world">world</option>
    <option id = "5" value="betting">betting</option>
    <option id = "6" value="wors">wors</option>
    <option id = "7" value="worsecter">worsecter</option>
    <option id = "8" value="bet2rand">bet2rand</option>
    <option id = "9" value="gom">gom</option>
  </select>
```

How do I select them?

`$('#select option')` **does not** work.

Help.

**EDIT** for these down voters:

Here is my full code, see for yourself if it works or not. dammit.

**selector.js**

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var options = [];
            $('#select').find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
            });
            $('#select').data('options', options);
            $('#textbox').bind('change keyup', function() {
                var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
                var search = $(this).val().trim();
                var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

                $.each(options, function(i) {
                    var option = options[i];
                    if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                        $('#select').append(
                           $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );
                    }
                });
                if (selectSingleMatch === true && $(select).children().length === 1) {
                    $('#select').children().get(0).selected = true;
                }
            });
        });
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#select').filterByText($('#textbox'), true);
    });

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#submit').click( function() {
            $('#select option').each( function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    });
```

**selector.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="selector.js"></script>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "selector.css">
</head>
<body>

  <input id="textbox" type="text" />
  <br>
  <br>

  <select id="select" multiple>
    <option id = "1" value="1">1</option>
    <option id = "2" value="234567890">234567890</option>
    <option id = "3" value="better">better</option>
    <option id = "4" value="world">world</option>
    <option id = "5" value="betting">betting</option>
    <option id = "6" value="wors">wors</option>
    <option id = "7" value="worsecter">worsecter</option>
    <option id = "8" value="bet2rand">bet2rand</option>
    <option id = "9" value="gom">gom</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <button id = "submit">OK!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the statement for selecting options executes after the select is added to DOM?

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/yhJ2C/ - Have you wrapped your code in [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: When i perform a function on $('#select'), it does work, does this mean it is added to the DOM?

Comment: Yup, it's in $(document).ready()

Comment: "`$('#select option')` does not work.": [No, it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/ExkRL/)

Comment: ps hide() is for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem.

If you add a logging statement to your code and then look at the console output (here is [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExkRL/1/)) then you can see that each option is selected.

If you examine the DOM, you can see that each option has `style="display: none;"` added to it.

The problem is that you cannot `display: none` an `<option>` element.

If you want to hide it, you have to remove it from the select entirely. e.g. by using `remove()` instead of `hide()` (as per [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExkRL/2/)).

Comment: Nope, submit is just the id of the button, see the bottom of my html in the question
:P

Answer (score 0):

We can use each function to get all the selected values at one click.

```
function getSelVal(){
    var foo = []; 
    var arr="";
    $('#mysel :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
         foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
         arr=arr+$(selected).text()+",";
    });
         arr=arr.substr(0,arr.length-1);
         $('#txtSelValues').val(arr);
}


<select id="mysel" multiple>
   <option id = "1" value="1">1</option>
   <option id = "2" value="234567890">234567890</option>
   <option id = "3" value="better">better</option>
   <option id = "4" value="world">world</option>
   <option id = "5" value="betting">betting</option>
   <option id = "6" value="wors">wors</option>
   <option id = "7" value="worsecter">worsecter</option>
   <option id = "8" value="bet2rand">bet2rand</option>
   <option id = "9" value="gom">gom</option>
</select>
```

please check it once here [JSFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/yhJ2C/1/)

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$('#select option').prop('selected', true);
```

**EDITED:**
before doing this, `MULTIPLE` attribute needs to be set to select tag first

happy Coding :)

Comment: OP mentioned in comments that *performing functions* on `$("#select")` works, but doing so on `$("#select option")` doesn't. He doesn't have an issue with performing actions on the elements, rather writing the selector for them. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: It's raining downvotes ^^. I guess people are upset for using a selector which OP said didn't work. Even though it works in a fiddle..

Comment: @RGraham: i was rather worried about how to select multiple elements than whats wrong with the selector, as the conclusion was to select multiple elements in one shot. any mere things on the way need not to be considered much.